# Recursive member initialization with vector resource handle

Tags: c++, c++11, initialization, member

The below code should obviously not compile (Equivalent to defining a class as `C { C myC }`, which would take infinite memory).  The question is how does C++ actually do the check?

```
class Node {
     vector<Node> mChildren{ Node }
}
```

When I try to compile, I get the following error.

```
trie.cpp:6:35: error: expected primary-expression before ‘}’ token
vector<Node> mChildren { Node };
                               ^
trie.cpp:6:35: error: could not convert ‘{<expression error>}’ from ‘<brace-enclosed initializer list>’ to ‘std::vector<Node>’
```

Is it because the class Node has yet to be fully declared?  How come I can use it as a template argument to vector.  A similar issue arises with

```
class C {
  C myC;
};
```

Comment: Your first version isn't equivalent to the C struct example at all. A `vector<Node>` doesn't contain a Node directly, only a pointer to an array of nodes. Your initialization makes no sense though.

Comment: In general you can't [place incomplete types in standard library containers](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18672135/241631). Your initialization is not syntactically correct though, you need this - `std::vector<Node> mChildren{ Node{} };` (you need a `Node` instance, not the type name, and there's a missing semicolon). If you do that replacement you'll start seeing errors about calling the default constructor before the class definition is complete.

Comment: You are missing a semicolon at the end of the Node class.

Comment: Thanks Prateorian.  I wish there was a way I could flag your comment as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems in you `Node` class. You are missing a semicolon at the end and you have a weird `{Node}` at the end of the line. Fix that and it will compile.

```
class Node {
  Node() {}
  vector<Node> mChildren= { Node() };
};
```

This compiles fine.

Comment: The whole idea is member initialize mChildren to contain a Node object.

Comment: class Node {
  vector<Node> mChildren = { Node };
};

Comment: Edited, still compiles fine for me.

Comment: That's pretty odd then, no?  Won't the default constructor create a vector of size 1 with a Node, that also has a vector of size 1 with a Node ...

Comment: It's a defect with the compiler apparently. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17430377/error-when-using-in-class-initialization-of-non-static-data-member-and-nested-cl