# `constructor required before non-static data member` - Am I hitting c++ core issue 1360 with a `boost::variant`?

Tags: c++, c++17, inner-classes, boost-variant

With this code

```
#include <boost/variant.hpp>
#include <string>

struct Outer
{
    struct StateA
    {
        std::size_t index = std::string::npos;
    };

    struct StateB {};

    using State = boost::variant<StateA, StateB>;

    struct Inner
    {
        State state = StateB{};
    };
};

int main() {
    Outer o;
    (void)o;
}
```

I get the following compilation error

```
/usr/include/boost/variant/variant.hpp:1301:17:   required from ‘class boost::variant<Outer::StateA, Outer::StateB>’
inner_class.cpp:18:30:   required from here
/usr/include/boost/type_traits/has_nothrow_constructor.hpp:27:84: error: constructor required before non-static data member for ‘Outer::StateA::index’ has been parsed
 template <class T> struct has_nothrow_constructor : public integral_constant<bool, BOOST_HAS_NOTHROW_CONSTRUCTOR(T)>{};
```

Referring to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17436088/390557) question, it would seem that I'm hitting [this](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1360) core issue, but I wanted to check my understanding.

Specifically, am I hitting

> an order dependency that is not specified in the current text

when my `typedef` of a `variant` is initialised in `Inner`?  Or is there something else about inner `struct`s that causes this compilation error?

Comment: I don't need `struct Inner` to get the compilation error ie. if I have a member variable `Outer::state` initialised in the same way, and delete the code for `struct Inner`, I get the same compilation error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn’t depend on anything being (found to be) `constexpr`, so it’s not identical to CWG1360, but it’s certainly similar in that it capitalizes on the impossibility of simultaneously having a nested class being a complete-class context for its containing class and having the nested class be complete later in the containing class than its definition.  Perhaps the best locus is [CWG2335](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#2335), for which the general (long-term) proposal has been made that actual dependencies within a class should be tracked by an instantiation-like mechanism; examples like yours ask for such a treatment *across* classes.

Comment: Thanks.  Where CWG2335 says "the function body of compute_right is not supposed to be evaluated until the class is complete", would you know where this evaluation order is defined?

Comment: @wreckgar23: That’s (implied by) [[class.mem]/6](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.mem#6.1), which says that the class is considered to be complete there (and so “forward lookup”—really deferred lookup—can occur).